# How does ASP.Net MVC replace the HTML tags with something that doesn't pars in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, unicode

If you generate an HTML string Like

```
ViewBag.FinalHTML="<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">StackOverFlow</a>";
```

and then Try to show it in View using this code:

```
This is the best Q&A for programming questions: @ViewBag.FinalHTML
```

then the result will be this:

```
This is the best Q&A for programming questions: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverFlow</a>
```

(I know how can I do that right. I have another question!)

How does ASP.Net MVC do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@` function uses the `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` method to safe encode everything you pass to it.

If you don't want this automatic encoding to happen use the `@Html.Raw` method:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.FinalHTML)
```

Obviously by doing this you should make sure that this `FinalHTML` is absolutely never coming from an user input but is generated by you on the server. Otherwise you are opening a huge XSS hole in your website.